# Logical conclusion. Is it possible to switch two statments.

Tags: logic

I need to get logical conclussion from this:
$$
p\implies\lnot q\\
q\\
---------\\
\lnot p 
$$

I think I can solve this problem with Modus Tollens, but the Q are not in the right position. Is it valid to make a new statment from this, to wor with. For example
$$
x=p\\
y=\lnot q\\
$$

$$
x\implies y\\
\lnot y\\
--------------\\
\lnot x\\
$$

Thanks!!!

Comment: Use the tableau method.

Answer (score 1):

If $p \Longrightarrow \lnot q$, then by the contrapositive $\lnot(\lnot q) \Longrightarrow \lnot p$

So $q \Longrightarrow \lnot p$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I have one more question. I did contrapositive on &p \implies q&, but now I got &Q\implies \lnot P \\ Q \\ ---- \\ \lnot P& so I concluded with Modus Ponens that the logical conclusion is correct. Did I do the right thing. Thanks

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to say. Can you say that again please?

Comment: I did contrapositive on P->~Q, which gave me Q->~P. Now I got: Q->~P, Q, where the logical conclusion is ~P. Now because I have this, can I use Modus Ponens to prove that logical conclusion is correct?

Comment: I don't really think you have to use modus ponens. We know that the contrapositive is EQUIVALENT to the positive. $p \Longrightarrow \lnot q$ is logically EXACTLY the same as $\lnot(\lnot q) \Longrightarrow \lnot p$. and this statement directly implies that $q \Longrightarrow \lnot p$. It all depends on how rigorous your instructor wants your proofs, I suppose, but I would just leave it at that.

Comment: Thanks. But it is possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

By [double negation introduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative_introduction) 
$$ {\color{green}{q}}\quad \vdash\quad \neg\neg {\color{green}{q}}$$
and by [modus tollens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens)
$$ {\color{green}{p}}\to{\color{red}{\neg q}},\ \neg{\color{red}{\neg q}}\quad \vdash \quad \neg {\color{green}{p}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose ¬¬p.  Suppose ¬p.  You have a contradiction right there, so by negation elimination you can infer p.  Then by (p⟹¬q) and detachment we obtain ¬q.  Since we have q we then have a contradiction.  So, by negation elimination we may infer ¬p.

Comment: I would like to inform you that there appears a box in "(p⟹¬q)" for me, where the conditional symbol ought to be. You may want to replace that character with a more universally supported one.